# How can I change the user identity that runs a build agent in TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-5.0

I am trying to get a build process set up in TeamCity 5, and I am encountering an access denied error when trying to copy some files.  I see that my build agent is running as "SYSTEM" now, and I think that's part of the problem.  I'd like to change that user identity.  The trouble is that I can't figure out how to change those settings on the build agent.  How can I change the build user identity?

Comment: I think this is a topic relevant to programming.  Superuser is not typically oriented around setting up automated build processes.

Comment: Sorry, I though TeamCity was some kind of game or something.

Comment: @George:  :)  It's not a very exciting game at all!  It's a pretty cool continuous integration framework, though.

Comment: it mightbe a CI framework, but it also reticulates splines.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

1. Open the services list (Start -> Run -> services.msc)
2. Find the "Team City Build Agent" service
3. Open the properties dialog for the service (right click, Properties)
4. Choose the "Log On" tab
5. Change the identity of the user running the service by choosing "this account" and enter the password.

Comment: I've done this and `user.name` still shows up as `SYSTEM`, even though the `user.home` points to the correct path.  Is this expected?  Is there some sort of refreshing I have to do?

Comment: I have the same problem. Anyone with a solution?

Comment: Open the properties dialog for the service - what does this mean? How do you find the service to open the properties dialog?

Comment: I've done this in version 8.1, and the `USERNAME` env var is showing up as `SERVERNAME$`.

Comment: From [Known Issues: Agent Running As Windows Service Limitations - TeamCity 8.x Documentation - Confluence](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Known+Issues#KnownIssues-AgentrunningasWindowsServiceLimitations): "As a Windows service, the TeamCity agent and the build processes are not able to access network shares and mapped drives." (Not sure how other CI engines such as Jenkins and TFS are able to, then.)

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham Did you restart the build agent service? That's what I had to do.

Comment: @sirdank - Hard to remember. Was 4 years ago ;)

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham Oops! Well maybe it will help someone.